# Race condition between creating file and ioutil.ReadFile

Tags: go, file-upload

I have a golang web app end point that allows uploading image, but I find that creating a file and immediately reading it using `ioutil.ReadFile` will result in `data` to be empty. But if I call it again in some time later it will contain the data.

```
    r.ParseMultipartForm(32 << 20)
    file, handler, err := r.FormFile("my_input_name")

    f, err := os.OpenFile("./img_dump/"+handler.Filename, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0666)
    if err != nil {
       return
    }
    // data is empty [] when first called
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/myAbsolutePath/img_dump/"  + handler.Filename)
    // This does not work, data is empty
    fmt.Println(len(data))

    f.Sync()

    data, err = ioutil.ReadFile("/myAbsolutePath/img_dump/"  + handler.Filename)

    // This does not work, data is empty
    fmt.Println(len(data))

    c1 := make(chan string, 1)
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 5)
        c1 <- "result 1"
    }()

    go func(name string) {
        select {
        case _ = <-c1:
            data, err = ioutil.ReadFile("/myAbsolutePath/img_dump/" + name)
            fmt.Println("after sleep")
            // This only works if I don't try f.Close(), data is not empty
            fmt.Println(len(data))
        }
    }(handler.Filename)
```

Is there a way to avoid race condition between creating and reading, maybe a promise?

Edit: I tried Sync to flush file but same issue still exist.

Comment: You are never actually _writing_ to `f` in this snippet...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [File.Sync](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Sync) ?

> Sync commits the current contents of the file to stable storage.
>   Typically, this means flushing the file system's in-memory copy of
>   recently written data to disk.

[Additional Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10862375/2285935)

```
f, err := os.OpenFile("./img_dump/"+handler.Filename, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0666)
if err != nil {...}

err = f.Sync()
if err != nil {...}

err = f.Close()
if err != nil {...}

data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/myAbsolutePath/img_dump/"  + handler.Filename)
```

Comment: hmm, I tried that, seems like the same issue persist

Comment: @user3591466 f.Sync needs to be called before you use ioutil.ReadFile and also can you try closing the file using f.Close before accessing it.